# No sound from headphones Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound, headphones

I am having some trouble getting sound when using headphones.
Restarting does not help but for some reason turning the computer off and then on again does. If the computer goes to sleep the sound in the headphones are gone when it wakes up, but the speakers work.

It shows that my headphones are connected in the sound settings, the sound is not muted and I have tried typing "alsamixer" in the terminal and checking the values.

aplay -l gives this. Not sure which card is which.

> card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: VT1802 Analog [VT1802 Analog]
>     Subdevices: 0/1
>
> Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
>
> card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 2: VT1802 Alt Analog [VT1802 Alt Analog]
>     Subdevices: 1/1
>
> Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

I know there is alot of these questions but I have not been able to solve my problem with any of the solutions I have found.

My computer is a Multicom Xishan W230S (Clevo W230SS)

Edit: Under "Play sound through" in the "output" tab in the sound settings it changes between "Headphones" and "Speakers" when I plug in/out the minijack. It says "Built-in Audio" on both of them.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install alsamixergui` and check the headphones and turn up the volume in `alsamixergui`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notebook has an headphone amplifier that is not initialized by the firmware after suspend, only on cold start.

More information: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1313904

Solution: Install https://github.com/Unrud/init-headphone-ubuntu/releases

Answer (score 0):

Speakers and Headphones are often listed as the same Device on Ubuntu, but sometimes the System does not realize changing output device. *Sound Settings* only shows available sound devices. E.g. a digital HDMI and an analog Speaker/Headphones

If you can't hear anything, it sometimes help to double-click on the Device you want to use!

Comment: I think maybe you misunderstood me. Under "Play sound through" in the "output" tab in the sound settings it changes between "Headphones" and "Speakers" when I plug in/out the minijack.
It says "Built-in Audio" on both of them.

Answer (score 0):

Jrgn, I had a similar problem for my headphones which did not seem to work on my PC. On gong into sound system settings, I found that both headphone jack and speaker output is listed as built-in audio.

However it was the speaker output(Line out) that was selected. The problem was solved by selecting headphone jack output and adjusting the volume.