# Headphones detected but no sound on 20.04

Tags: sound, 20.04, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I have spent the last 3 days reading through forums and trying different fixes but nothing seems to work for me.

### Observed behaviour

The headphones are detected, and both `alsamixer` and `pavucontrol` switch device when plugged. `pavucontrol` shows the volume bar moving as if audio was indeed being played, not I can't head anything. The moment I unplug my headphones, audio is played on speakers correctly.

### Attempts at fixing the issue

- Playing with pavucontrol and alsamixer: one popular solution seems to be the below commands. **This had worked in the past, but I had to wipe Ubuntu and install it again from scratch and the second time it didn't work.**

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get upgrade
  sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
  sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio pavucontrol
  sudo alsa force-reload
  ```
- At the end of [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1829568) thread, there is the idea of adding `'options snd-hda-intel index=0 model=headset-mode,asus-g73jw'` to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`. Given that I don't have that model I tried instead

  ```
  'options snd-hda-intel index=0 model=headset-mode'
  ```

  and

  ```
  'options snd-hda-intel index=0 model=asus-mode1'
  ```

### System description

Dual-booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

```
sudo lshw
luispc                      
    description: Notebook
    product: GL503VM
    vendor: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
    version: 1.0
```

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC295 Analog [ALC295 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

**EDIT:** I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1272908/ubuntu-20-04-headphones-detected-but-no-sound) post where the situation is identical, and his solution was my second attempt. Yet, didn't work for me. It seems to be ASUS-related though.

Comment: Could it be related to this issue? https://askubuntu.com/questions/587131/no-sound-from-headphones-ubuntu-14-04?rq=1

Comment: The issue you mention @NikolajHansen concerns Clevo laptops and mine is ASUS. Besides, I don't get audio on headphones even from a cold start.

Comment: you are right, but I think you should focus more on the chipset on your sound card than the make of your laptop. Google tells me lots have problems with it.